# BREW TBT Process?

Tags: brew-framework, brewmp

I am new To TBT Process. If i want to test my build in TBT for a particular device, I have to pay, OK...  but If want to test for another device model, do I have to pay again? After passing TBT process, how can I sell that build, will they provide single file or MOD with MIF, like that? What I have to go through result build? Any help please?

Comment: Hopefully this process will be simplified in BrewMP... I'm not an expert in BREW acceptance testing, but older TBT guides describe a process that seems quite complicated (and costly) compared to Apple/Android app store processes.

Answer (score 1):

With TBT, you pay each time you submit a build. You pay less if you are adding a device to your existing application submission.

Once the app passes, it is listed in your Qualcomm extranet site. No, you do not get a build. Qualcommm holds the certified build with them and then you contact the operator willing to have your application listed with the content id.

Its a completely locked down system so my advice is not to get into the platform unless you have a operator willing to take on your application.